# C#8 nullable and non-nullable reference types - nullable output only if input is nullable

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a bunch of extension methods that convert my entities to `DTOs` like the following.

```cs
public static LocationDto? ToDto(this Location? @this)
{
    if (@this == null) return null;

    return new LocationDto
            {
                Id = @this.Id,
                Text = @this.Name,
                ParentId = @this?.Parent?.Id,
            };
}
```

The issue here is that if you pass not nullable entity still receive a nullable and you cannot define a `public static LocationDto ToDto(this Location @this)` because they would be compiled to the same method.
Also, I don't like to use `!` for the time I am calling it. So the following is not my answer.

```cs
Location entity = AMethod();
LocationDto dto = entity.ToDto()!;
```

Is there an attribute or syntax to tell the compiler how this method behaves? Somehting like:

```cs
public static [NullableOnlyIfInputIsNull] LocationDto? ToDto(this Location? @this)
```

Comment: c#-9.0 has nullable reference types.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez yes, you are right. C# has it since C#8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute you are asking for is [NotNullIfNotNullAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullifnotnullattribute?view=net-5.0)

The attribute accepts the name of the parameter you use to infer nullity.

In your case this would look like:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

// ...

[return:NotNullIfNotNull("this")]
public static LocationDto? ToDto(this Location? @this)
{
    // Your code here
}
```